# Filtering using ARMA model in R

Tags: r, time-series, arma, filter

I have two time-series, `x` and `y`. I would like to prewhiten `x` by fitting an ARMA(p,q) (or in my case ARMA(1,1)) process and then use the coefficients to filter `y`. This seems like a pretty standard thing to want to do.  However, the `stats:::filter` function does only MA or AR filtering it looks like.  What is the appropriate way to do this? Also, should one use the `arima` function in R to do this or are there other ways?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think this does what you want:

```
library(forecast)
fit <- Arima(x,order=c(1,0,1))
yfiltered <- residuals(Arima(y,model=fit))
```

Comment: could you please explain how `Arima` with `model` parameter works? in particular: if i filter `x` with $(1-aL)x_{t} = (1-bL)\varepsilon_{t}$, this can be accomplished by `fit <- Arima(x,order=c(1,0,1))`, correct? Then when I run `residuals(Arima(y,model=fit))`, does this produce $y_{t}-[(1-aL)y_{t} - (1-bL)u_{t}]$ where $u_{t}$ are residuals of $(1-aL)y_{t})$?

Comment: Yes. See help file: "model: Output from a previous call to Arima. If model is passed, this same model is fitted to x without re-estimating any parameters."

Comment: yes, took a look. was having trouble udnerstanding what was meant by residuals. think i have it now. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I suggest three different functions:

> stats:::arima
>
> forecast:::Arima
>
> forecast:::auto.arima

forecast:::auto.arima will automatically seelct the p and q lags for you.